# undocumented http status codes in apache log files

Tags: apache, http, grails, http-status-codes

I am working on a Grails application which uses Apache as front end and a Tomcat server to run the application. In order to check for people that are
logged in I send, via Ajax, a signal that generates a response from the clients every minute when there is no apparent activity on a client.

In the Apache log files I find entries that have status codes that I can't understand. The responses look like this (IP stands for the IP number and some other info is changed, DateAndTime instead of real date and time and ... for uninteresting info):

```
IP - - [DateAndTime] "POST /rapp/admin/AXpush HTTP/1.1" 200 420 "..."
IP - - [DateAndTime] "POST /rapp/admin/AXpush HTTP/1.1" 200 581 "..."
IP - - [DateAndTime] "POST /rapp/admin/AXpush HTTP/1.1" 200 581 "..."
IP - - [DateAndTime] "POST /rapp/admin/AXpush HTTP/1.1" 200 581 "..."
IP - - [DateAndTime] "POST /rapp/admin/AXpush HTTP/1.1" 200 581 "..."
IP - - [DateAndTime] "POST /rapp/admin/AXpush HTTP/1.1" 200 5867 "..."
IP - - [DateAndTime] "POST /rapp/admin/AXpush HTTP/1.1" 200 581 "..."
IP - - [DateAndTime] "POST /rapp/admin/AXpush HTTP/1.1" 200 581 "..."
IP - - [DateAndTime] "POST /rapp/admin/AXpush HTTP/1.1" 200 581 "..."
IP - - [DateAndTime] "POST /rapp/admin/AXpush HTTP/1.1" 200 581 "..."
IP - - [DateAndTime] "POST /rapp/admin/AXpush HTTP/1.1" 200 5867 "..."
...
```

There is exactly one minute between calls.
Now I wonder what the numbers 420, 581 and 5867 stand for. I can find some info about 420, saying: "Enhance Your Calm" whatever that means. For the codes 581 and 5867, I find nothing.

Comment: in `200 581`, **200** is the status code and **581** is quite certainly the size of the response (depends on your logFormat).

Answer (score 0):

I see that I deserve the -1 here. Of course these numbers are not status codes. I still wonder about the 5867, as it is different and all calls are exactly the same, but thanks [regilero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/550618/regilero) for putting me on track. I'll find out about the rest.